# How do I mathematically prove $ \sin^3(3t)$ is periodic?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I am given $$x(t) = \sin(3t)$$ and asked to mathematically show that $x^3(t)$ is periodic, how exactly would I do this?

Comment: Hint: any one-valued function of a periodic function is periodic.

Comment: Hint: if $f(t)$ is periodic, then there exists a $T>0$ such that $f(t) = f(t+T)$ for all $t$...

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $\sin\left(3\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\right)=\sin(3x)$. It follow from this that$$\sin^3\left(3\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\right)=\sin^3(3x)$$and that therefore your function is periodic wih period $\frac{2\pi}3$.

Comment: I think that misses the point of the question a bit, which seems to be mostly about the third power, not the periodicity of $\sin(3t)$.

Comment: @quud I assumed that the OP is aware of the fact that if two numbers are equal, then so are their cubes.

Comment: Well, it's hard to be sure as the question is not overly detailed. But given how the post is phrased, I suspect what I said. And, while phrased as in your comment, I'd assume that OP does know this, I also assume that they in fact did not realize they had to use (only) this, and pointing it out right away would have made for a better answer. I suggest you [edit] your answer to include this information.

Comment: @quid Done. I would like to know what the OP thinks about this.

Answer (score 0):

Since $t\mapsto\sin(t)$ has period $2\pi$, the function $t\mapsto\sin(3t)$ has period $2\pi/3$.
If you "speed up" by factor three, you expect the period to get shorter by the same factor.
The third power has the same period as the original function.

You don't have to approve of the argument above as a proof.
It does give you a reason to suspect that the period of $x^3$ might be $2\pi/3$.
To check whether that is the case, start computing $x^3(t+2\pi/3)$ and see whether after simplification it is $x^3(t)$.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you!